# Default reviewers for a branch in multiple repositories

Tags: gerrit

```
Gerrit Version: 3.2.3
Reviewers Plugin: aebc8574de - (3.2.11-SNAPSHOT).
```

We have `5k` gerrit repositories and in that `1k` repositories we have branches `dev/test/2022` & `dev/release/2022` uniquely.

Is it possible to configure the default code reviewers for above given branches in multiple repositories globally at one place? instead of configuring it in each repository explicitly.

So that whenever developer pushes a change in any of the specified branch in a repository, it need to add the reviewers automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the reviewers plugin is configured per project in the reviewers.config file, missing values are inherited from the parent projects, so a global default configuration can be done in the reviewers.config file of the All-Projects root project (or another parent project), and the other projects can then override the configuration in their own reviewers.config file, if necessary.

See the plugin documentation [here](https://github.com/davido/gerrit-reviewers-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md).

Comment: Thanks Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira.